# How to find sub-string and replace it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following rows:

```
Name               Url
name1              http://foo.com/this/that
name6              http://that.net/hello
name2              http://foo.com/hello/world
name3              http://foo.com/world/hello
name4              http://hello.com/this/that
```

I need to write a query that will change every `foo.com` to `hello.com`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the REPLACE() function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx.  You should be able to use that in an UPDATE statement to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE <table name> SET Url = REPLACE (Url, "foo.com" , "hello.com")
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function:

```
update table set url = replace(url, 'foo.com', 'hello.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table
SET Url = REPLACE(url, 'foo.com', 'hello.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET Url = REPLACE(url, 'http://foo.com/', 'http://hello.com/')
```

it's safer!!